# Cypress Github action throwing an error during run

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress, github-actions

I am trying to set up a simple Cypress Github action that tests the code being pushed to each branch and also before it's merged. But I seem to be getting an error every time. I don't know if it has to do with the node version used by cypress-io/github-action@v2, no matter what I do, it keeps throwing this error. Below are my related files from my project.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "crossa-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@stitches/react": "^1.2.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "apisauce": "^2.1.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "axios-retry": "^3.2.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "docker:build-image-staging": "docker-compose build --no-cache staging",
    "docker:build-image-prod": "docker-compose build --no-cache prod",
    "docker:staging": "docker-compose up staging",
    "docker:prod": "docker-compose up prod",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "plugin:cypress/recommended"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.9",
    "cypress": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0"
  }
}
```

cypress.yml

```
name: Cypress Tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
      - staging
      - prod
    pull_request:
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm start
```

Here is the error on Github Actions
[image]

[image]

Please if anyone has done this with the latest react release, please help me out.

Comment: Annnnnd... which error? :p

Comment: @dbuchet Sorry, added it. It totally skipped my mind.

Comment: Do you have the last versions of `@storybook/*` ?

Comment: @dbuchet its buggy with the latest version of react, so I had to revert to version that works.

Answer (score 1):

try to add "--legacy-peer-deps" to your run:

```
    name: Cypress Tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
      - staging
      - prod
    pull_request:
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies 
        run: npm ci --legacy-peer-deps
      - name: Show Cypress information ℹ️
        run: npx cypress info
      - name: Verify Cypress can run ‍♂️
        run: npx cypress verify
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm start
```

Comment: I don't see "--legacy-peer-deps" anywhere in your example code